# CAML <AND> causes ServerException

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I'm trying to execute following CAML-query to SharePoint within Client Object Model:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2014-10-10</Value>
            </Geq>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2014-10-20</Value>
            </Leq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
                <Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="TRUE" />
    </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Looks simple and obvious, but it causes ServerException in .NET
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot join more than two expression in and tag
add another and like the ones marked with ----

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And> ---
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2014-10-10</Value>
            </Geq>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2014-10-20</Value>
            </Leq>
        </And> --- 
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
            <Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Is this rule true for <Or></Or> ? Does it mean I must use many nasty ORs/ANDs when I have complicated condition?

Comment: yes it is also for <Or></Or>. and yes you must use many nasty ors and ands